# Where should i store my temporary view model in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a page where users can select an answer from random questions.

The controller contains

```
 public class TestController : Controller
        {

            private DBDataContext _context;
            private HomeViewModel _model;

            public TestController()
            {
                _context = new DBDataContext();
                _model = new HomeViewModel();
            }

            // GET: Test 
            [Route("test-online")]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                _model = new HomeViewModel()
                {
                    Categories = _context.Categories.Select(x => x.ToCategories()).ToList(),
                    QuestionModel = new List<QuestionModel>()
                };

                ViewData.Model = _model;

                return View(_model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public void Go(Test t)
            {
                _model = (HomeViewModel)ViewData.Model;
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_context != null)
                    {
                        _context.Dispose();
                        _context = null;
                    }
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
}
```

And the problem is where should i store my `_model`?

When a user selects an answer an ajax post is performed onto the `Go` method,
but unfortunately the `ViewData.Model` is now `null`

How can i fix this issue?
I tried both with `ViewBag` and `ViewData` since i do not want to use a public static property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your model via `Session` like following code.

**// part where you set the model and session**

```
var _model = new HomeViewModel()
{
    Categories = _context.Categories.Select(x => x.ToCategories()).ToList(),
    QuestionModel = new List<QuestionModel>()
};
Session["model"] = _model;
```

**// part where you get the model and session**

```
HomeViewModel model = null;
if(Session["model"] != null)
{
    model = Session["model"] as HomeViewModel;
    // your code here
}
```

> What can be done for application pool reset case to dont lose Session data?

Session state works `inProc` mode which stores session state in memory on the Web server as a default, to dont lose session variables in case of application pool reset you can change state mode to `StateServer` or `SQLServer` which provides a solution to make session state preserved when the Web application is restarted.

Detail reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Should i ask what happens with the data on application pool reset?

Comment: for application pool reset case, i would recommend to change session-state mode. reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are saving your model temporarily to use it in another method, you should use TempData instead.

Instead of ViewData in Index method, use TempData. Ex :

```
TempData["myModel"] = _model;
```

You can retrieve the same in your Go method by using

```
_model = TempData["myModel"];
```

Please remember that TempData will hold the data for only one request. If you want data to persist for more than one request , you need to use TempData.peek and TempData.keep. You can find what it is from the below link

https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/mvc-when-to-use-keep-vs-peek-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Should i ask what happens with the data on application pool reset?

Comment: When you dig into how TempData works, it is nothing but a perishable object stored in SESSION . So when you use TempData and if your app pool is recyled or reset, data availability will entirely depend on what state management technique you use... What @hsnbl has said in his comments will match for this case as well